# Where clause for particular guard

Tags: haskell

I have a piece of Haskell code below. The problem is the clause `(enigmaInput,_) = (filter (\(a,b) -> b == cipherChar0) stecker)!!0` will fail for the first 2 guards. How can I assign it for the last 2 guards only. Thanks!

```
 followMenu :: Crib->Menu->Stecker->Offsets->Maybe Stecker
 followMenu c [] s o = Just s
 followMenu crib menu stecker offsets 
  | (length stecker) == 1 && initAdd == Nothing = Nothing
  | (length stecker) == 1 && initAdd /= Nothing = followMenu crib (tail menu) (fromMb initAdd) offsets
  | (length stecker) /= 1 && normalAdd == Nothing = Nothing
  | otherwise = followMenu crib (tail menu) (fromMb normalAdd) offsets
  where (_,_,cipherChar0) =  crib!!(menu!!0)
        (_,_,cipherChar1) =  crib!!(menu!!1)
        (enigmaInput,_) = (filter (\(a,b) -> b == cipherChar0) stecker)!!0
        enigmaOutput = enigmaEncode enigmaInput (SimpleEnigma rotor3 rotor2 rotor1 reflector1) offsets
        (_,initInput) = stecker!!0
        initOutput = enigmaEncode initInput (SimpleEnigma rotor3 rotor2 rotor1 reflector1) offsets
        (_,_,initCipher) = crib!!(menu!!0)
        initAdd = steckerAdd initOutput initCipher stecker
        normalAdd = steckerAdd enigmaOutput cipherChar1 stecker
```

Comment: You are missing a big opportunity to simplify your code. You do not need to check explicitly what values `initAdd` and `normalAdd` have; just define `fm = \add -> followMenu crib (tail menu) add offsets`, then call `fmap fm initAdd` and `fmap fm normalAdd` depending on the length of `stecker`.

Comment: Also pattern matching on `stecker` instead of checking length and indexing will clean things up too, I think it will even address your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need to, since `(filter (\(a,b) -> b == cipherChar0) stecker)!!0` won't be evaluated until the value of `enigmaInput` is needed, and you don't use `enigmaInput` in the first two guard cases. This is a nice feature of lazy evaluation.

There is no way to attach a `where` clause to some but not all of a set of guarded equations, besides restructuring your pattern matches and guards of course.

Comment: When I try a 2 element `stecker` it works fine but when I try 1 element `stecker`, I got this error `*** Exception: Prelude.!!: index too large` so I guess it's because of `(filter (\(a,b) -> b == cipherChar0) stecker)!!0` returns an empty list for 1 element `stecker`

Comment: Well that's impossible if you really don't use `enigmaInput` in either of the first two cases. It's more likely one of the many other uses of `!!` in your program.